# wget : several downloaded *.xz files aren't of the expected size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, wget

[image]

When I run `sudo apt update` on **Repo DMZ** after syncing all **Commands-amd64.xz** files from **https://archive.ubuntu.com**, the command completes without any errors but the same command on **Repo LAN**, after syncing it from **Repo DMZ**, returns several errors that some files downloaded with wget are slightly larger by 20 to 40 bytes.

NB : The VirtualHost on **Repo {DMZ | LAN}** only listens on its ip address, HTTP connections are redirected to HTTPS and the sources.list is configured with the URL **https://srvrepo{dmz | lan}.intra.local**

Original command (example) :

`wget -q -c -r -np -R "index.html*" --ca-certificate=/etc/ssl/certs/intra.local_ca_chain.pem https://srvrepodmz.intra.local/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz -O /repo/mirror/srvrepodmz.intra.local/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz`

Current command used (same result as above) :

`wget --ca-certificate=/etc/ssl/certs/intra.local_ca_chain.pem https://srvrepodmz.intra.local/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz -O /repo/mirror/srvrepodmz.intra.local/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64.xz`

How can I download the same files on Repo LAN as those on Repo DMZ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!